# Do any 4TB single-sided NVME drives exist?

Tags: hard-drive, thinkpad, nvme

I just purchased a Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 9, and a [Sabrent 4TB Rocket 4 PLUS (SB-RKT4P-4TB)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08VF99PV8). Though both of these are NVME Gen 4, to my chagrin, the NVME drive purchased does not fit into the Thinkpad. It's too thick.

[image: Two sided NVME and one sided nvme]

[image: One sided NVME on top of two sided NVME]

Are there any NVME drives above 2TB that are one-sided? Is there any mechanism in which I can shop this without purchasing them all and opening them up?

Comment: Ask Lenovo Support.  I have your machine right here plus an older X1 and a Lenovo M70s and the only SSD I can to fit is a 1 TB SSD.

Comment: Why would Lenovo tell me if any 4 TB Single-sided SSDs exist? Presumably they're only the authority on what _they_ sell. However, they do tell me this hardware supports 2 TB SSDs.

Comment: I cannot answer that. My X1 Gen 9 is a month old, made to order and 1 TB was max.

Comment: @John There are **certainly** 2TB drives that work in this unit, regardless of if Lenovo sells it.. https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/thinkpad-x1-carbon-gen-9

Comment: It may be the long warranty I have requires Lenovo Parts.

Comment: @John I can tell you from experience on that one all of my X1 Carbons have upgrades and that unofficially the warranty doesn't care. ;) They still make house calls and fix keyboards/touchpads/screens when they break.

Comment: @EvanCarroll the link you've shared clearly shows an answer and a solution to your question. Why not simply go with the crucial drive if they sell it as compatible?

Comment: @mashuptwice link does not have a 4TB drive, (as specified in question) I just provided it to show that exceeding the capacities _sold_ by Lenovo is **certainly** possible. Which is entirely off-topic, imho as nothing about this question is about Lenovo or Thinkpads, just single-sided NVME in the abstract. Lenovo isn't the only one that does this, I think a lot of ultra-portables are doing it now.

Comment: @EvanCarroll sorry, I've missed the "above"

Comment: @mashuptwice all good, it happens.

Comment: There are now certainly 4 TB single sided NVMEs which should make this on topic, since we known they exist.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum component height is defined in the type number by two characters after the first hyphen:

[image]

[Source: PCI Express M.2 Specification Rev 1.0 p.23](https://web.archive.org/web/20210118201723/http://read.pudn.com/downloads794/doc/project/3133918/PCIe_M.2_Electromechanical_Spec_Rev1.0_Final_11012013_RS_Clean.pdf#page=23)

While this doesn't directly answer your question, this information should make it easy for you to find a drive with the correct specification.

Comment: That's only for TE drives, not an industry standard. The drive I just purchased (linked above) is the Sabrent 4TB Rocket 4 PLUS (model number SB-RKT4P-4TB). It doesn't seem to follow that convention.

Comment: @EvanCarroll This is valid for all M.2 drives from any manufacturer. Note that there is a difference between a standardized devices type number and a manufacturers model number.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I've edited the post with the same table from the official M.2 specification to avoid any further confusion.

Comment: So without knowing how I can get a list of "standardized devices type number" how can I use this to answer whether or not such a drive exists?

Comment: @EvanCarroll As you can clearly see from the chart, any drive with S1-S3 as the 5th & 6th digit of the type number is single-sided.

Comment: And where do I even find the "standardized devices type number" given a manufacturer's model number? IE., all I have is this SB-RKT4P-4TB

Comment: @EvanCarroll The [M.2 specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20210118201723/http://read.pudn.com/downloads794/doc/project/3133918/PCIe_M.2_Electromechanical_Spec_Rev1.0_Final_11012013_RS_Clean.pdf#page=23) mentions the PCB thickness on page 21 to be 0,8mm +-10%. The single-sided maximum component height is 1,2mm, 1,35mm, or 1,5mm. [WD mentions "physical dimensions"](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-blue-ssd/product-brief-wd-blue-3d-nand-sata-ssd.pdf) in their datasheets. 1/2

Comment: @EvanCarroll 2/2 1. get a datasheet for your current WD drive or measure the physical dimensions of your current drive (remember, the type number is `2dWidth 2dLength - 2dHeight - A - B`, or `WWLL-HH-A-B`)  2. do a bit of maths: `componentHeight = (( <yourWDDriveThickness> - 0,8mm ))` 3. find a drive with compatible dimensions (`WWLL-HH`), interface (`A-B`) and the desired or available max capacity. Either let your vendor deal with finding a device based on the specs, or use one of the price comparison websites or other search tools to find one.

Comment: You keep speaking about these things like (a) they exist, or (b) they'll give me a data sheet. You have 0 evidence for any of these claims in your answer. I use Amazon and new egg. As it pertains to single-sided they don't allow you to "find a device based on the specs"

Comment: @EvanCarroll Whoa, calm down. Nobody can help you to understand the technology if you do not believe in industry standards. You can however go to any PC shop and let a professional choose a specific drive for your needs, without understanding or even knowing about the standardized M.2 form factors that are currently produced and sold.